# uibootsrap double datepicker-popup not updating ngmodel

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building a simple table to edit and add information. everything works fine except the update of ngmodel from uib-datepicker-popup. I've tried several codes but still no success. I even tried without the directive, and got the input updated but the model doesn't update. Here is the sample (version with directive)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('shopsCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
  $scope.myData = [{"idshops":"1001","nome":"Colombo","idfirmas":4,"zona":1,"data_abertura":"2005-07-01","data_fecho":null,"ip":"192.168.181.1","ip2":"192.168.181.2","ip3":null},{"idshops":"1002","nome":"OeirasPq","idfirmas":4,"zona":1,"data_abertura":"2005-07-01","data_fecho":null,"ip":"192.168.105.3","ip2":null,"ip3":null},{"idshops":"1003","nome":"Vasco da Gama","idfirmas":4,"zona":1,"data_abertura":"2010-09-30","data_fecho":null,"ip":"192.168.183.1","ip2":null,"ip3":null},{"idshops":"1004","nome":"Aeroporto de Lisboa ","idfirmas":4,"zona":1,"data_abertura":"2005-07-01","data_fecho":null,"ip":"192.168.184.1","ip2":null,"ip3":null},{"idshops":"1005","nome":"Amoreiras","idfirmas":4,"zona":1,"data_abertura":"2016-09-01","data_fecho":null,"ip":"192.168.185.1","ip2":null,"ip3":null}];
  angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(values, key) {
   values['myid']=key;
  });
  $scope.myDataM = $filter('filter')($scope.myData, {idfirmas: 4}, true);
  $scope.myDataA = $filter('filter')($scope.myData, {idfirmas: 2}, true);
  $scope.myDataB = $filter('filter')($scope.myData, {idfirmas: 3}, true);
  $scope.myDataI = $filter('filter')($scope.myData, {idfirmas: 1}, true);

  $scope.totalItemsM = $scope.myDataM.length;
  $scope.totalItemsA = $scope.myDataA.length;
  $scope.totalItemsB = $scope.myDataB.length;
  $scope.totalItemsI = $scope.myDataI.length;
/*pagination*/
 $scope.Mselected = {};
 $scope.Aselected = {};
 $scope.Bselected = {};
 $scope.Iselected = {};
 $scope.itemsPerPage = 11;
 $scope.currentPageM = 1;
 $scope.setPageM = function (pageNo) {
  $scope.currentPageM = pageNo;
 };
 $scope.currentPageA = 1;
 $scope.setPageA = function (pageNo) {
  $scope.currentPageA = pageNo;
 };
 $scope.currentPageB = 1;
 $scope.setPageB = function (pageNo) {
  $scope.currentPageB = pageNo;
 };
 $scope.currentPageI = 1;
 $scope.setPageI = function (pageNo) {
  $scope.currentPageI = pageNo;
 };
/* fim pagination
   inicio template edit/view */
 $scope.getTemplateM = function (shops) {
  if (shops.myid === $scope.Mselected.myid) return 'editM';
  else return 'displayM';
 };

 $scope.editRowM = function (shops) {
  $scope.Mselected = angular.copy(shops);
  $scope.dt = $scope.Mselected.data_abertura===null ? null : new Date($scope.Mselected.data_abertura);
  $scope.dt2 = $scope.Mselected.data_fecho===null ? null : new Date($scope.Mselected.data_fecho);
 };
 $scope.saveRowM = function (idx) {
  var mypost = angular.extend({action: 'gravarow'}, $scope.Mselected);
    $scope.myDataM[idx] = angular.copy($scope.Mselected);
    $scope.resetM();
 };
 $scope.addRowM = function(){
  $scope.myDataM.push({'myid': $scope.myData.length, 'idshops': null, 'nome': null, 'idfirmas': '1', 'zona': null, 'data_abertura': null, 'data_fecho': null, 'ip': null, 'ip2': null, 'ip3': null});
  $scope.myData.push({'myid': $scope.myData.length, 'idshops': null, 'nome': null, 'idfirmas': '1', 'zona': null, 'data_abertura': null, 'data_fecho': null, 'ip': null, 'ip2': null, 'ip3': null});
  $scope.setPageM(Math.round($scope.totalItemsM / $scope.itemsPerPage));
  $scope.editRowM($scope.myData[$scope.myData.length - 1]);
 }

 $scope.resetM = function () {
  $scope.Mselected = {};
  $scope.dt = new Date();
  $scope.dt2 = new Date(2020, 5, 22);
 };
/* fim templates 
   inicio calendario */
 $scope.dtpopup = {opened: false};
 $scope.dtpopupopen = function($event){
   $event.preventDefault();
   $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.dtpopup.opened = true;
 }
 $scope.dt2popup = {opened: false};
 $scope.dt2popupopen = function($event){
   $event.preventDefault();
   $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.dt2popup.opened = true;
 }
 $scope.resetM();
 $scope.dtOptions = {
  showWeeks: true,
  maxDate: $scope.dt2,
  minDate: null,
  startingDay: 1
 };
 $scope.dt2Options = {
  showWeeks: true,
  maxDate: null,
  minDate: $scope.dt,
  startingDay: 1
 };
/* $scope.$watch('dt', function(e){
  $scope.Mselected.data_abertura = $filter('date')(e, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  $scope.dt2Options.minDate = $filter('date')(e, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 });
 $scope.$watch('dt2', function(e){
  $scope.Mselected.data_fecho = $filter('date')(e, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  $scope.dtOptions.maxDate = $filter('date')(e, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 });
/* fim calendario */
 $scope.focus = function(e){
  e.target.select();
 }
// Object.keys(datag).toString()
 $scope.tabs = [{title:'Mi', disabled: false},{title:'Az', disabled: true},{title:'Bb', disabled: true},
  {title:'Ing', disabled: true}];
});
myApp.directive('csDateToIso', function () {

     var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs, shopsCtrl, filter, http) {

         shopsCtrl.$parsers.push(function (datepickerValue) {
             return moments(datepickerValue).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
         });

     };

     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: linkFunction
     };

 });
```

```css
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="shopsCtrl">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div >
<div ng-bind="dt"></div>
<div ng-bind="dt2"></div>
<div class="btn pull-right" id="ihelp"><span class="glyphicon icon-help"><img src="../images/logo_help.jpeg"/></span></div>
<uib-tabset active="active">
 <uib-tab index="0" heading="Mi" disable="tab.disabled">
 </br>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td class="dthead">Id</td>
     <td class="dthead">Nome</td>
     <td class="dthead">Zona</td>
     <td class="dthead">Data Abertura</td>
     <td class="dthead">Data Fecho</td>
     <td class="dthead">IP 1</td>
     <td class="dthead">IP 2</td>
     <td class="dthead">IP 3</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
    <td colspan="9" style="text-align: center;">
     <ul uib-pagination direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" total-items="totalItemsM" ng-model="currentPageM"></ul>
    </td>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in myDataM | limitTo : itemsPerPage : (currentPageM - 1) * itemsPerPage" ng-include="getTemplateM(x)">
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="9"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="addRowM()"></i></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </uib-tab>
 <uib-tab index="1" heading="Az" disable="tab.disabled"></uib-tab>
 <uib-tab index="2" heading="Bb" disable="tab.disabled"></uib-tab>
 <uib-tab index="3" heading="Ing" disable="tab.disabled"></uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
</div>
</body>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="displayM">
  <td>{{ x.idshops }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.nome }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.zona }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.data_abertura }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.data_fecho }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.ip }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.ip2 }}</td>
  <td>{{ x.ip3 }}</td>
  <td style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit btn btn-info btn-lg" ng-click="editRowM(x)"></i>
  </td>
 </script>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="editM">
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="3" maxlength="4" ng-model="Mselected.idshops" ng-required="true" /></td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="30" maxlength="50" ng-model="Mselected.nome" ng-required="true" /></td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="1" maxlength="1" ng-model="Mselected.zona" ng-required="true" /></td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;">
   <div class="form-group"><p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" csDateToIso uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' ng-model="dt" is-open="dtpopup.opened" datepicker-options="dtOptions" ng-change="dtchange()" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dtpopupopen($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
   </p></div>
  </td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;">
   <div class="form-group"><p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" csDateToIso size="8" maxlength="10" uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="dt2" is-open="dt2popup.opened" datepicker-options="dt2Options" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dt2popupopen($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
   </p></div>
  </td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="11" maxlength="15" ng-model="Mselected.ip" ng-required="true" /></td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="11" maxlength="15" ng-model="Mselected.ip2" /></td>
  <td style="padding: 4px 0px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" size="11" maxlength="15" ng-model="Mselected.ip3" /></td>
  <td style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="saveRowM($index)"></i>
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out btn btn-danger btn-lg" ng-click="resetM()"></i>
  </td>
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I've solved it after a lot of debugging on the browser console. there is a "this" object that stores the new date so i used it to update the scopes with ngchange and also removed the directive and the prevent defaults. who ever is interest can check the code here "https://plnkr.co/edit/fE4FF7d1pVavRCCeAVXW". there are still some improvements to make but the basic works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'dt' and 'dt2' from the 'editM' template are being used as the model for all rows.  In your template you might have to add something to make the model unique per row like an $index (which Angular gives you for free on ngRepeat.